# yahoo_fin request limit?

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance

I just developed a code to get fundamental data from yahoo using the yahoo_fin module. Here the code. the problem is that after retrieving information from 20 stocks it starts to fail and not retrieve any data. Any idea of how can I solve this? I used time.sleep(10) but not working.

Here the code.
...

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import datetime
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime as dt
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import time


count=0
DiagnosticsResearch=['GTH', 'MYGN', 'CSTL', 'LNTH', 'PSNL', 'SRDX', 'VIVO', 'FLDM', 'QTNT', 'OXFD', 'CNTG', 'ARA', 'DMTK', 'XGN', 'ENZ', 'STIM', 'BNGO', 'BWAY', 'BASI', 'CELC', 'MOTS', 'HTGM', 'NDRA']
tickers= DiagnosticsResearch


for i in range(len(tickers)):
    ticker=tickers[i]

    try:
        count=count +1 
        df_bs= pd.DataFrame(si.get_balance_sheet(ticker, yearly=True))
        df_is=pd.DataFrame(si.get_income_statement(ticker, yearly=True))
        df_cf=pd.DataFrame(si.get_cash_flow(ticker, yearly=True))
        print (tickers[i] + " Ok")
        if count>=20:
            time.sleep(20)
        else:
           time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print (tickers[i] + "->NOT OK")
        if count>=20:
            time.sleep(20)
        else:
           time.sleep(1)
        pass
```

...

the output is the next one

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCDiw.png)

Sometimes it retrieves 10 stocks, some other 20, some other 4

any idea on how to solve this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Did the complete run ever execute?

Is it possible while you were developing this code and executing calls to the API that you exceeded the 2000 call limit per hour, or have you definitively not come close to the limit?

3 calls per ticker * 20 tickers = 60 calls per run potentially while developing.

I am wondering if there is a velocity constraint as well.